# PyQt's "pyqtProperty" VS python's standard "property"

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, pyqt5

I have a few questions regarding the `pyqtProperty` class of PyQt5 package, and the standard built-in `property` class of python:

1. Why use `pyqtProperty` over standard property? The codes given below works in both ways. What's the advantage of using `pyqtProperty` instead of Python's plain old `property` (used as a decorator on a method)? I know that I must specify the return type of a `pyqtProperty`, but why would I want to use it?
2. Does `pyqtProperty` inherits from `property`? The attribute `pyqtProperty.__mro__` does not show that (the result is `PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtProperty, object`) and I can't find a source code file of `pyqtProperty`. [PyDoc's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html) command refers to a `.pyd` file of the module `PyQt5.QtCore` (which is not a source code plain text file), and there is no stub file for it. But the command `help(pyqtProperty)` gives me information **very similar** to the one get with `help(property)`, **different** from the one found on the [official documentaion](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/PyQt5/qt_properties.html#PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtProperty). So, where that information comes from?
3. Why the methods decorated with `@pyqtProperty` or even with `@property` are **executed when the Qobject is set up**?

   Back to the codes given below: the property methods (in the both cases `@pyqtProperty` and `@property`) are executed before creating the attribute `_custom_property`, which gives a `AttributeError`. But that should not happen, and really does not happen with `@property` decorator with regular python classes (I've tried that too, there's a snipet below). When I use simple getter and setter methods (not decorated), that doesn't happen at all (which is normal). The strangest phenomenon is: this `AttributeError` occurs when I run in debug mode. In normal mode (`python main.py`) the property methods get executed anyway, but the error is not raised.

I'm using PyQt5 version 5.9.2 installed with Anaconda Distribution, python 3.8.

---

This is the contents of Ui_MainWindow.py file, generated with pyuic5:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(419, 196)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 419, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

---

This is the content of the `main.py` file using `property` decorator:

```py
from Ui_MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self._custom_property = 1
    
    @property
    def custom_property(self):
        print("This method is executed")
        return self._custom_property

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

---

This is the content of the `main.py` file using `pyqtProperty` decorator:

```py
from Ui_MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtProperty

class MainWindow(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self._custom_property = 1
    
    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def custom_property(self):
        print("This method is executed")
        return self._custom_property

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

---

I won't put the content of the main file with no decorator (just remove the `@` lines in the code above).
But this is a simple file with `property` decorator showing it is not executed in the `__init__` method

```py
class Test:
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    
    @property
    def x(self):
        print("This method is not executed in init")
        return self._x
    
    def setx(self,value):
        self._x = value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Test()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The **difference** between pyqtProperty and property, **not an advantage**, is that these properties will be accessible through the metaObject that Qt has, and this last tool is used for various tasks in Qt such as exposing properties in QML, being able to be used in QtStyleSheet, being used in QPropertyAnimation, etc.
2. [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) as `pyqtProperty` is a descriptor so it should not necessarily inherit from property ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) is an example of how to create descriptors without inheriting from property). If you want to know the implementation of pyqtProperty then you should check the qpycore_pyqtproperty.h and qpycore_pyqtproperty.cpp file in the qpy/QtCore folder of [the source code](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/a4/d5e4bf99dd50134c88b95e926d7b81aad2473b47fde5e3e4eac2c69a8942/PyQt5-5.15.4.tar.gz).
3. The `custom_property` method call is caused by [`QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName) but I think it is a bug. This method tries to make the semantic connection if the name of the method meets a certain pattern: `on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>)`. I point out that it is a bug since if I implement the same logic with PySide2 I do not observe that behavior.

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc, you really helped. I didn't know much about descriptors, I'm still learning the basics of python. Regarding that last item: I really think it is a bug with `connectSlotsByName()` (in this one I already knew about the `on_obj_signal` thing) because of [this thread](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2019-August/042003.html). It seems to be solved in PyQt new version, but it [seems to be difficult for Anaconda to update it](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11183#issuecomment-518822063)

Comment: @Diogo I do not know if it is the same error, I am using the latest version of PyQt5 and I get the error. Try PyQt6 since maybe there it has already been solved since I see unlikely a new release of PyQt5

Answer (score 1):

The answer by eyllanesc is complete enough, but I'd like to extend it by explaining some situations for which using a `pyqtProperty` is actually required and using standard python properties won't suffice:

### Qt StyleSheets

QSS provide access to Qt properties:

1. for [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types), it's possible to define a rule whether a property matches the specified value; for instance, you could change the color of all buttons that are labelled `Ok` or `Cancel`:

```
QPushButton[text="Ok"] {
    color: green;
}
QPushButton[text="Cancel"] {
    color: red;
}
```

Note that changing the value of a property that defines appearance when the widget has already been displayed ("polished" by the style) requires to recompute the stylesheet again. In the above case, if you change the text of the button from "Ok" to "Cancel", you won't see any change in the text color. In order to achieve that, it's required to *re-set* the stylesheet by means of `obj.setStyleSheet(obj.styleSheet())`, which can be done on the widget itself *or* any of the parents that have a stylesheet set (including the QApplication).
The easiest way is to do `self.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet())` in the setter of the property (possibly, after checking if the value has actually changed), which will work even if the widget has *no* style sheet set and the rule is defined on any of its ancestors.

2. it's possible to *set* properties, as long as their types are supported by QSS:

```
#Window {
    qproperty-minimumSize: 300px 300px;
    qproperty-geometry: rect(250 250 400 400);
}
```

Note that, as the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#setting-qobject-properties) explains, "the qproperty syntax is evaluated only once, which is when the widget is polished by the style", so you cannot set properties with pseudo-states (like the `:hover` state) as they will probably be ignored or provide unexpected and unreliable behavior.

### Item delegate editors

By default, item delegates set the value of an editor using its [user property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#userProperty).

```
class MyCustomEditor(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    # ...
    QtCore.pyqtProperty(object, user=True)
    def myCoolProperty(self):
        # ...
```

This means that if you have a custom editor and use a Qt property declared with the *user* flag, you only need to implement `createEditor()` to return the custom editor (or even define the editor in a custom [QItemEditorFactory](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemeditorfactory.html) for specific data types), and `setEditorData()` will automatically set its value without worrying about  the index, the data type or the property name.

### Designer plugins

This is more of a fringe scenario, as creating plugins for designer is rarely needed and it is *not* an easy task (the PyQt documentation is scarce and mostly outdated, and some features and functions provided for C++ are not implemented). But, if you do need it, the only way to have custom properties shown in the property editor box of a custom widget created with a plugin is to use Qt properties.

Comment: Thankyou musicamante. I will keep eyllanesc's answer as the solution, but these situations you explained were really helpful.

Comment: @Diogo don't worry: eyllanesc's answer is the proper answer and it should be left as the accepted one; I didn't post mine as "more valid": I only wanted to add some insight, as I know that there's some "gray area" in the documentation that can usually be discovered and properly understood only after getting a *lot* of experience. Qt is a *huge* and very extended toolkit, and while the docs are normally very well written, they cannot cover any aspect and explanation. It took me a lot of time to get used to it, and I believe I should make my efforts useful to others too.